# Composing A Set Of Paths From Points

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of 2D measurements, which are taken from paths (roads and sidewalks). 
Each point belongs to a specific path, and I assume that there is no error in measurements.

However these points are not divided and not ordered, so I can't directly restore the paths from them.

I want to cluster these points, and order each cluster into a list, so each list will assemble a polyline that represents one of the paths.

My assumptions are that points on the same path are not "too far" from each other, and that paths do not change direction rapidly (they do not zig and zag). 
This means that a road that has a 90 degrees turn is actually two paths, which is a good result.

Note that I am not looking for some interpolation, but I am looking for a set of polylines that are the closest to the ground truth.

I tried using a simple heuristic:

1. Find the center
2. Find the point that has the most distance from the center
3. Find the closest next point, which is "close enough" and the azimuth change is "small enough"
4. Repeat (3) until all points in that path are found.
5. Repeat (2) until all paths are found.

This gave decent results.

I wonder if there are any known algorithms, or approaches for this problem?
Are there any similar problems that have known answers?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You might consider sharing a link to a Google Drive or Dropbox file containing the points and/or a plot of them.

Comment: I think this is a special case of mesh reconstruction in 2D. There's a lot of literature on reconstructing 3D meshes from point clouds, since the output of laser scanners is a point cloud and meshes are much more practical than them.